# INSERT using results of CTE INSERT to provide unique id values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am writing a job to transform data from an old design into a new design. In this process, I need to take the id from an insert into a separate table and use that in an insert to the target table, as such:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 {
  t1_id BIGSERIAL,
  col1 VARCHAR
};
CREATE TABLE t2 {
  t2_id BIGSERIAL,
  col2 VARCHAR, -- renamed from col1 to avoid confusion
  t1_id BIGINT REFERENCES t1.t1_id
};
```

I have the SQL defined that matches the following form:

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO t1 (t1_id) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING t1_id
) INSERT INTO t2
  (col1, t1_id)
SELECT
  a.val1, (SELECT * FROM ins)
FROM t3 a;
```

I wanted this to run the `SELECT * FROM ins` for every row of the `SELECT` .. but instead it only runs it once and uses that value for all rows in the `SELECT`.  How can I restructure my SQL to get the desired behavior?

*edit4*

t1 ends up looking like:

```
1,<NULL>
(1 row)
```

t2 ends up looking like:

```
10,'a',1
11,'b',1 -- problem with id from t1 being 1
12,'c',1 -- problem with id from t1 being 1
.
.
```

What I want t1 to look like:

```
1,<NULL>
2,<NULL>
3,<NULL>
.
.
```

What I want t2 to look like:

```
10,'a',1
11,'b',2 -- id from t1 of 2
12,'c',3 -- id from t1 of 3
.
.
```

*edit*
To address what a_horse_with_no_name said, I also tried this (with the same result):

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO t1 (t1_id) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING t1_id
) INSERT INTO t2
  (col1, t1_id)
SELECT
  a.val1, b.t1_id
FROM t3 a
JOIN ins b ON TRUE;
```

*edit2*
I just tried directly referencing the appropriate `SEQUENCE` in my query, and that DOES work - but I don't like that solution very much at all (mostly because I don't like hard-coding object names.)  If there is ANY solution other than directly referencing the name of the `SEQUENCE` I would appreciate it. :)

*edit3*
I suppose another solution would be to make use of a `PROCEDURE` to do the `INSERT` instead of a CTE .. but I'd still appreciation options/suggestions.

Comment: You need to join `ins` and `t3`

Comment: I tried that as well and it still only calculated the value only once. But perhaps I didn't have my join quite correct. I will edit my post to show what I tried with that.

Comment: You are inserting only one row into `t1` and not supplying any value for `t1.col1`. Where should the data come for that column? Is `t1.col1` related to `t2.col1`?

Comment: ypercube - t1.col1 is allowed to be NULL and will be inserted in a later process. Because I was referencing the CTE as a SUBSELECT in the actual row values, I figured it would be executed more than once - but it turns out that I was incorrect in that assumption .. which is why I'm asking this question here. I've already tried researching for an answer on google for the past few hours and have been unable to find what's correct yet. And no, t1.col1 is not related to t2.col1 .. sorry for that confusion.

Comment: Still, `INSERT INTO t1 (t1_id) VALUES (DEFAULT)` inserts only 1 row into `t1`. So i t doesn't matter if you put the `ins` in the `FROM` clause and join it to `t3` or not. Can you show us how you would insert 2 (or more) rows into `t1`? And more important, how you know which of the 2 (or more) `t1.id` values would be matched to the rows inserted into `t2`?

Comment: That's just it - I don't know HOW I would go about doing that. I would like to know how I can get that to insert more than one row into t1 and use the resulting values in the top most insert.

Comment: I'll ask again the same thing - in a different way. Which columns of `t3` have values that will be inserted into `t1`?

Comment: None, actually. I need to reserve a row in t1 FOR t3. It's actually the opposite. I need to take the id column (which doesn't exist yet - thus creating it via insert) from t1 and use it in t3.

Comment: Then all the rows from `t3` (and thus in `t2`) will be related to a different `t1.id`? Or somehow grouped? It would really help everyone understand what exactly you are up to, if you had used real table and column names and even better, if you had provided sample rows, with real data.

Comment: Related to a different t1.id is correct, yes. I don't see why the real table and column names would matter - I provided an SSCCE (minus t3 and dummy data generation for t3 .. so I suppose that's missing). However, I will edit my post and add example results to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't understand why you need 2 tables if they have only 1-1 relationship. But here it is (`pk` is the primary key of `t3`):

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO t1 (col1) 
    SELECT NULL FROM t3 
  RETURNING t1_id
) 
, r AS
( SELECT t1_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM ins
) 
, t AS
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM t3
) 
INSERT INTO t2
  (col1, t1_id)
SELECT
  t.val1, r.t1_id
FROM t 
  JOIN r USING (rn) ;
```

If your t3 is the results of a SELECT instead of a preexisting table, you can implement it as such so that you don't have to repeat the t3 query twice:

```
WITH t3 AS (
  SELECT ...
), ins AS (
  INSERT INTO t1 (col1)
    SELECT NULL FROM t3
  RETURNING t1_id
), r AS (
  SELECT t1_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM ins
), t AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM t3
) INSERT INTO t2
  (col1, t1_id)
SELECT
  t.val1, r.t1_id
FROM t 
  JOIN r USING (rn);
```

Comment: The reason why I need the two tables is because there is another table that also will need to store values in t1..  (t1 will have links to both t2 and t4) t1 is meant to be a table for contact information (with fkeys to address, email, and phone number tables) and t2 and t4 are both entities in different domains that will need to have contact information associated with them.. I may have some of my vocabulary incorrect, but that's essentially why. Thank you for the answer - I will go test it out.

Comment: Edited a minor mistake. Use the latest version.

Comment: OK, it makes sense then. But you may not need the `t2_id` at all. Seems you can you use the `t2(t1_id)` as the PK of `t2`.

Comment: :) It's giving me a syntax error with DEFAULT at the moment - trying to figure out what it might be. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
LINE 2:             DEFAULT AS contact_detail_id`

Comment: Hm, It seems `DEFAULT` can't be used that way. Nor returning the `t.pk`

Comment: Aye - it's also saying that t3.pk is out of scope for the `INSERT` (as you just mentioned above). I will keep working on it, though - at least I have more direction now. Thank you.

Comment: I will try this when I get in to work tomorrow - but a question ... won't the row numbers not match up if I end up running it more than once?

Comment: The row numbers will match up, as long as you use the same `FROM t3` in both places.

Comment: I got sidetracked with other stuff at work - but I have time to get back to this currently - I will test out and see about implementing your suggestion above. If it does work, I'll mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Alright - I finally had a chance to try this out and it works. :) I made a minor change to it (in case anyone else seeks to do something along these lines) because my t3 actually wasn't an existing table but actually the results of a query. So that I didn't have to have my query in the solution duplicated, I will edit your answer and add what I did.

Comment: Just for reference in case anyone else may find this useful - the above solution was able to perform ~600k inserts in 1.5 minutes on a single core VM (no reservation on GHz) running CentOS with 4 GB of RAM assigned to it. Not super detailed for a benchmark, but possibly enough to give others a suspicion.

Comment: I amend my above statements. I have intermittently gotten horrendous performance from this due to a nested loop without any index to use. ypercube - as far as I know, it's not possible to specify an index on a CTE .. do you know of any way to potentially get the join between r and t to use something other than a nested loop?

Comment: I wasn't considering efficiency at all with this as it seemed like a one-time operation. I can imagine that with millions (or billions) of rows, it won't scale well.

Comment: Ok. No worries. Most runs would actually be a relatively small amount of data (I'm not working with a huge db) .. but no worries. It sounds like for my situation a procedure is the way to go. I was hoping to avoid one just simply to keep the solution all in one place.

Comment: If `t3` is the result of a previous query, you will probably improve this by storing it into a temporary table (with the row_numbers) and indexing it.